# Wordpress Theme Installation Issues - Critical Error Message

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I tried to install a new theme to a larger existing blog but keep getting this message:

--
Warning: require(/home/customer/www/truck.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/autopro/inc/custom-post-types.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/customer/www/truck.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/ti/functions.php on line 489

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/truck.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/autopro/inc/custom-post-types.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') in /home/customer/www/truck.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/ti/functions.php on line 489

### There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

I was hoping to stage the site on Siteground but when that didn't work I went directly to wordpress and was trying to install the theme with demo content in order to start working on it.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: PHP is telling you that the file `custom-post-types.php` couldn't be found in `/wp-content/themes/autopro/inc/`, hence the fatal error. Double check that the file actually exists in that location.